# Надёжный способ обновить поля в таблице с джойнами

Tags: delphi, oracle, ado

Имеется таблица Details с кучей полей вида T_REZKA_NV, T_REZKA_CEQ, T_REZKA_PRIM и т.п. Чтобы не плодить лишних сущностей, было решено сделать отдельную таблицу OperDetails и поместить в неё несколько дополнительных операций. Увы, заказчики требуют, чтобы всё это безобразие было представлено в одной таблице, доступной для редактирования. Соответственно было проверено несколько вариантов, и были получены результаты разной степени удручаемости.

1. Селект с джойнами

   ```sql
   SELECT details.*,
     OperDetails.T_NV T_REZKA2_NV
   FROM Details
   LEFT JOIN OperDetails
   ON Details.NREC = OperDetails.CDetails
   ```

   по идее, это наиболее простой вариант, но ADOQuery выдаёт ошибку при попытке внести изменения в поле заджойненной таблицы (ищет поле T_NV в Details) и часто не находит запись, на которой стоит курсор дбгрида.
2. Lookup-поля без джойнов. В данном случае теряется событие вставки новой записи, не сразу обновляются данные в таблице, да и вообще как-то всё очень криво работает.
3. Calculated поля. Тут нельзя поменять значение поля через грид. Nuff said.

Также пробовал поля типа InternalCalc, но в АДО они оказались идентичны обычным дейта-полям. Помню, где-то видел, как можно сгенерировать предложения вставки и модификации динамически из селекта, но оказался бессилен найти снова. [Здесь можно посмотреть код более подробно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140560/get-current-cell-value-in-dbgrid).

Прошу объяснить, что можно сделать в данном случае, кроме как плюнуть, и впихнуть всё в Details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со стороны базы данных можно сделать вьюшку для Вашего запроса, которая будет выставлять этот запрос как единую таблицу. А для этой вьюшки сделать [instead of trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c18trigs.htm#10901), чтобы она поддерживала DML.

Пример:

```
--drop table Details;
--drop table OperDetails;

--1. Создадим тестовые таблицы и заполним их данными
create table Details
(
  nrec int,
  value varchar2(10)
)
/

create table OperDetails
(
  CDetails int,
  T_NV varchar2(10)
)
/

insert into Details 
select 1, 'first' from dual union all
select 2, 'second' from dual union all
select 3, 'thrid' from dual
/

insert into OperDetails
select 1, 'T_NV 1' from dual union all
select 2, 'T_NV 2' from dual
/

--2. Создадим вьюшку над нашими таблицами
create or replace view DetailOperDetails
as
select d.nrec, d.value, od.t_nv t_rezka2_nv
from Details d
left join OperDetails od on d.NREC = od.CDetails
/

--3. Создадим instead of trigger
create or replace trigger DetailOperDetails_trg
instead of insert or update or delete
on DetailOperDetails
for each row 
begin

  case 
    --Для вставки данных
    when INSERTING then
      insert into Details values(:new.nrec, :new.value);
      insert into OperDetails values (:new.nrec, :new.t_rezka2_nv);

    --Для обновления данных  
    when UPDATING then
      update Details set value = :new.value where nrec = :new.nrec;

      --Делаем merge, т.к. данных в OperDetails вообще может не быть
      merge into OperDetails od
      using (
        select :new.nrec cdetails, :new.t_rezka2_nv t_nv from dual
      ) s on (s.cdetails = od.cdetails)
      when not matched then 
        insert values (s.cdetails, s.t_nv)
      when matched then
        update set od.t_nv = s.t_nv;

    -- Для удаления
    when DELETING then
      delete from Details where nrec = :old.nrec;
      delete from OperDetails where CDetails = :old.nrec;
   end case;

end;
/

--4. Пробуем DML над вьюшкой
update DetailOperDetails set t_rezka2_nv = 'T_NV_3' where nrec = 3;
insert into DetailOperDetails values (4, 'fourth', 'T_NV 4');
delete from DetailOperDetails where nrec = 1;

--5. Смотрим результат
select * from DetailOperDetails
/
```

Comment: Неплохо, но у нас 9-й оракл, `instead of` не сработает :(. Хотелось бы всё-таки решение на delphi.

Comment: Жаль, что не смог Вам помочь. Надеюсь, что Вам предложат что-нибудь полезное на delphi.

Comment: А хотя нет, работает :)

Comment: Тогда я рад, что смог предложить полезный вариант =)